# Can't run add-apt-repository due to gi error on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.8.5

Tags: 18.04, apt, python3

I am trying to run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

on Ubuntu 18.04 using Python 3.8.5.

I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

I have tried to build the symlinks in the /gi package:

[image]

But I keep getting the same error. I had the same issue with Python 3.7 but it was solved by the well known solution with symlink.

Please advise how can I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what helped me to fix the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838238/importerror-cannot-import-name-gi-from-partially-initialized-module-gi-mo

And the solution was to force install:

```
sudo python3.8 -m pip install --ignore-installed PyGObject
```